# Getting field from vector of objects C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a graph class in C++. I am storing the edges for each node as a vector of the Edge class. The Edge class has a `getWeight()` function, but it is returning strange values.

I think it has something to do with getting copies of the Edges rather than the actual Edges that have been allocated.

**Heres the Edge class:**

```
#ifndef EDGE_INCLUDED
#define EDGE_INCLUDED
#include "Node.h"


class Node;


class Edge {

    private:
        Node endpoint;
        double weight;

    public:
        Edge();
        Edge(const Edge &edge);
        double getWeight() const;
        void setWeight(double weight);
};
#endif // End EDGE_INCLUDED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include "Edge.h"
#include "Node.h"

Edge::Edge(){}
Edge::Edge(const Edge &edge) {}

double Edge::getWeight() const { return this->weight; }

void Edge::setWeight(double weight) { this->weight = weight; }
```

**Here's the Node class**

```
#ifndef NODE_INCLUDED 
#define NODE_INCLUDED

#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Edge;

class Node {
    private:
        std::string label;
        std::vector<Edge> edges;

    public:
        const std::string getLabel() const;
        void setLabel(std::string label);

        const size_t degree() const;

        std::vector<Edge> getEdges();
        void setEdges(std::vector<Edge> edges);
};
#endif // End NODE_INCLUDED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include "Node.h"
#include "Edge.h"


const std::string Node::getLabel() const { return this->label; }

void Node::setLabel(std::string label) { this->label = label; }

const size_t Node::degree() const { return this->edges.size(); }

std::vector<Edge> Node::getEdges() { return this->edges; }

void Node::setEdges(std::vector<Edge> edges) { this->edges = edges; }
```

**And finally here's the main**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Edge.h"
#include "Node.h"


int main()
{
    Edge edge1;
    Node node;

    std::vector<Edge> edges;

    edge1.setWeight(2.0);

    edges.push_back(edge1);

    node.setEdges(edges);

    std::vector<Edge> e = node.getEdges();

    for (auto i : node.getEdges())
        std::cout << i.getWeight() << std::endl;
}
```

Sorry for posting so much code but I was hoping somebody would be able to see where I am going wrong here. **Can anybody see my mistake and point me towards a better design?**

Comment: It's all fine and dandy but how are you going to use this graph? Your edge has cipies of its endpoints, and each endpoint copy has copies of its edges, and each copy of each edge has *its own* copies of its endpoints and ... ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Edge`'s constructors, you don't initialize the member `weight`. Hence, you are seeing uninitialized, garbage values.

Change them to:

```
Edge::Edge() : weight(0.0) {}
Edge::Edge(const Edge &edge) : weight(edge.weight)  {}
```

Comment: This worked. Can you elaborate a little more on why calling `setWeight()` doesn't work?

Comment: `setWeight` works just fine. The problem arises when copies of `Edge`s are made, which happens in `node.setEdges(edges);` and in `... e = node.getEdges();` .